# Java Unrecognized option: -xvf

Tags: java, windows, jar, cmd

I was trying to extract Java jar file as

java -xvf my.jar but it throws error

```
Unrecognized option: -xvf
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java` is the wrong command for this, and ommit the `-`. Use `jar xvf my.jar`

Comment: using your command something like this                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xvf
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xvf
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
      Could not find the main class: xvf.  Program will exit.

Comment: You are still using java. Use jar.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `java` command in there
i.e. you only need to do `jar xvf jarName.jar`